# Applying an operator on both sides of an equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

I am doing a quantum mechanics question involving the positivity of the norm. So I'm using the fact that the norm will be greater than zero but i want to apply an operator onto the ket on one side of the equation, is it a legal operation to apply the operator to the zero on the other side and say its still zero?

Comment: Is the operator linear? If so, linear operator applied to null vector gives you a null vector

Comment: yea its a linear operator, but is a null vector the same as just the number 0?

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no. You can often interpret functions, or vectors, or other math objects as vectors of a **vector field**, while "number $0$" is a scalar

Comment: A null vector is a vector of magnitude $0$. There is only one such vector in a vector space.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense as written. How are you acting with an operator on the norm, which is a scalar? Can you write out precisely what you are trying to do?

Comment: Am I right in interpreting this as: you know that $\| k \| > 0$, where $k$ is some ket, and you have some operator $A$ on kets, and what you are asking is whether $\|A k\| > 0$? That depends on the operator $A$. If $A$ is non-singular, then yes, that will be true. But if $A$ is singular, then $k$ could be in the null space of $A$, so $Ak = 0$.